# How to close firefox from a batch file without killing the process?

Tags: batch-file

Hi I want to close a Firefox window but without killing it...
I know that the taskkill command terminates processes but is there any other way to close the application window?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't kill a process without killing the process. However, unless you use the `/f` switch `taskkill` asks the process nicely to terminate itself (same as if you'd press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>).